# How do I get the difference between two timestamps?

Tags: bash, scripting, timestamps

I am creating a simple backup script. I would like to have a message saying "You last backed up x days ago" on login. I can create a file when I do the backup "backup/.last_backup_timestamp" but what format should I use and how would I find the difference in days between then and now in bash?

Thank-you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `date` utility to write the timestamp of a `file`, and the current time, as seconds elapsed from the Epoch, then format a string to convert the seconds of the difference in days with `bc`:

```
echo "scale=2; ($(date +%s)-$(date -r file +%s)) / (3600 * 24)" \
  | bc
```

Comment: You don't need `bc` for that: `echo $(( ( $(date +%s) - $(date -r file +%s) ) / 3600 / 24 ))`

Comment: @Mat: I know, but a fraction of day could be important.